Why can't I display commas in the argument of `\affiliation`?
I meet one issue. I want to show commas in lines such as

Mathematical Sciences Department, University MATH1, 40024, a city, a country

in affiliation. How to add comma? I have tried \textcomma, \comma and \char,{}` but without success. Hope for your discussion and help.
The code is attached.
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\journal{Journal of King Saud University - Science}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
        
\title{TITLE TITLE}

\author[1]{xxx\corref{cor1}}
\ead{email 1}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\author[1]{YYY\corref{cor1}}
\ead{email 2}

\author[1]{ZZZ}

\author[1]{MMM}

\author[2,3]{NNN}

\affiliation[1]{Mathematical Sciences Department, University MATH1, 40024, a city, a country
  }

\affiliation[2]{
  Mathematical Sciences Department, University MATH1, 40024, a city, a country}

\affiliation[3]{
 Mathematical Sciences Department, University MATH2, 40025, a city, a country}

\fntext[fn1]{Research was funded}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract is as below.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
This is keyword.
\end{keyword}
        
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}

The outPDF is attached. Note: no commas shown in the affiliation lines.


I've taken the liberty of simplifying your preamble considerably, in order to focus readers' attention on the main subject. Feel free to revert.

A general remark: It's a good idea to keep the affiliations lines short. The shorter, the better. There's no advantage to overloading the affiliation lines with geographical tidbits (such as city and country).

@Mico, it is ok for me, the question should indeed be simplified, thank you for this good suggestion, I will adopt it. As for the city-state, although your proposal makes sense, this is based on the requirements of my mentor and I don’t have the final say.

The argument to \affiliation should be a list of key-value pairs: in the manual of elsarticle (page 5) there's the example
\affiliation[1]{organization={Elsevier B.V.},
  addressline={Radarweg 29},
  postcode={1043 NX},
  city={Amsterdam},
  country={The Netherlands}}

Not all the keys are mandatory.
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\journal{Journal of King Saud University - Science}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
        
\title{TITLE TITLE}

\author[1]{xxx\corref{cor1}}
\ead{email 1}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\author[1]{YYY\corref{cor1}}
\ead{email 2}

\author[1]{ZZZ}

\author[1]{MMM}

\author[2,3]{NNN}

\affiliation[1]{
  organization={Mathematical Sciences Department, University MATH1},
  postcode={40024},
  city={a city},
  country={a country},
}

\affiliation[2]{
  organization={Mathematical Sciences Department, University MATH1},
  postcode={40024},
  city={a city},
  country={a country},
}

\affiliation[3]{
  organization={Mathematical Sciences Department, University MATH2},
  postcode={40025},
  city={a city},
  country={a country},
}

\fntext[fn1]{Research was funded}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract is as below.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
This is keyword.
\end{keyword}
        
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}


The manual is just 18 pages long and it's rich in examples.

Thanks for your explanation for "affiliation"! It is a good answer!
